# Simplifying big expression

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, fourier-analysis, closed-form

What to do with this?

$$f(x) = \frac{\sinh(\pi)}{\pi} + \frac{2\sinh(\pi)}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n \left[\frac{\cos(nx)-n \sin(nx)}{1 + n^2}\right]$$

Can it be simplified?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have:
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x \cos(n x)\,dx = 2\sinh(\pi)\frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}$$
$$\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^x \sin(nx)\,dx = 2\sinh(\pi)\frac{(-1)^{n+1} n}{1+n^2}$$
hence over $I=(-\pi,\pi)$ we have:
$$ e^x = \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}+2\frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(-1)^n\frac{\cos(nx)-n\sin(nx)}{1+n^2}$$
and the given series is just the Fourier series of $e^x$ over $I$.

Comment: This is a nice answer ! Cheers